# Linker Errors while including another Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I am trying to include this [project](https://github.com/sinabio/Eleven) in my swift. This project uses ffmpeg player. So i dragged the entire file under my project. I had many compile time errors and I resolved them. Finally I am getting linker errors. These are the errors:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_deflateReset", referenced from:
      _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
      _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)
      _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
  "_deflateBound", referenced from:
      _encode_png in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
      _encode_apng in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
      _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
      _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      _matroska_decode_buffer in libavformat.a(matroskadec.o)
      _rtmp_open in libavformat.a(rtmpproto.o)
      _swf_read_header in libavformat.a(swfdec.o)
      _decode_frame_apng in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      _decode_frame_png in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      _decode_text_chunk in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      _flashsv_decode_init in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
      ...
  "_BZ2_bzDecompressInit", referenced from:
      _matroska_decode_buffer in libavformat.a(matroskadec.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      _png_enc_init in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _http_read_stream in libavformat.a(http.o)
      _matroska_decode_buffer in libavformat.a(matroskadec.o)
      _rtmp_open in libavformat.a(rtmpproto.o)
      _zlib_refill in libavformat.a(swfdec.o)
      _decode_frame_common in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      _decode_text_chunk in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
      ...
  "_inflateReset", referenced from:
      _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
      _zlib_decomp in libavcodec.a(lcldec.o)
      _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(tscc.o)
      _zerocodec_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(zerocodec.o)
      _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(zmbv.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      _http_read_header in libavformat.a(http.o)
  "_BZ2_bzDecompress", referenced from:
      _matroska_decode_buffer in libavformat.a(matroskadec.o)
  "_BZ2_bzDecompressEnd", referenced from:
      _matroska_decode_buffer in libavformat.a(matroskadec.o)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _avcodec_open2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _avcodec_open2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_uncompress", referenced from:
      _id3v2_read_internal in libavformat.a(id3v2.o)
      _mov_read_cmov in libavformat.a(mov.o)
      _swf_read_packet in libavformat.a(swfdec.o)
      _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(cscd.o)
      _decode_frame in libavcodec.a(dxa.o)
      _decode_block in libavcodec.a(exr.o)
      _g2m_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(g2meet.o)
      ...
  "_compress", referenced from:
      _encode_strip in libavcodec.a(tiffenc.o)
  "_compress2", referenced from:
      _flashsv2_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv2enc.o)
      _flashsv_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsvenc.o)
  "_uregex_close", referenced from:
      _clearCacheSlotRegex in RegexKitLite.o
  "_u_errorName", referenced from:
      _userInfoDictionary in RegexKitLite.o
      _RKLNSExceptionForRegex in RegexKitLite.o
  "_inflateSync", referenced from:
      _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
  "_uregex_findNext", referenced from:
      _rkl_find in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_splitArray in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_appendReplacement", referenced from:
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_end", referenced from:
      _rkl_find in RegexKitLite.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _http_close in libavformat.a(http.o)
      _http_read_header in libavformat.a(http.o)
      _matroska_decode_buffer in libavformat.a(matroskadec.o)
      _rtmp_open in libavformat.a(rtmpproto.o)
      _swf_read_close in libavformat.a(swfdec.o)
      _decode_frame_apng in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      _decode_frame_png in libavcodec.a(pngdec.o)
      ...
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
      _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
      _flashsv2_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv2enc.o)
      _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)
      _encode_frame in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
  "_uregex_start", referenced from:
      _rkl_find in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_reset", referenced from:
      _rkl_splitArray in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_u_strlen", referenced from:
      _userInfoDictionary in RegexKitLite.o
  "_zlibCompileFlags", referenced from:
      _http_read_header in libavformat.a(http.o)
  "_uregex_find", referenced from:
      _rkl_find in RegexKitLite.o
  "_deflateInit_", referenced from:
      _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
      _flashsv2_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv2enc.o)
      _encode_init in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)
      _encode_init in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
  "_uregex_open", referenced from:
      _getCachedRegex in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_appendTail", referenced from:
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_groupCount", referenced from:
      _getCachedRegex in RegexKitLite.o
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      _png_enc_close in libavcodec.a(pngenc.o)
      _flashsv_decode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv.o)
      _flashsv2_encode_frame in libavcodec.a(flashsv2enc.o)
      _flashsv_encode_init in libavcodec.a(flashsvenc.o)
      _flashsv_encode_end in libavcodec.a(flashsvenc.o)
      _encode_end in libavcodec.a(lclenc.o)
      _encode_init in libavcodec.a(zmbvenc.o)
      ...
  "_uregex_setText", referenced from:
      _clearCacheSlotSetTo in RegexKitLite.o
      _setCacheSlotToString in RegexKitLite.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As far as I understand these are errors in .a files. When i run the original project it was running fine but when i included it in my project I am getting these errors. How can I solve these errors?

Comment: i think you need to install pods

Comment: Try to use cocoa pods instead of adding manually: https://cocoapods.org/?q=ffmpeg

Comment: pods are already installed in that project. Infact i can even add that pod lib in my build phases

Comment: @nynohu thank you i will check it

Answer (score 1):

need add some dylib framework. 
Add "libz.dylib" to framework from the target -> Build Phases tab -> Link Binaries With Libraries,
you can search framework by error key 
hope that will work for you.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. It's now called "libz.tbd" which is basically a string file pointing to the library.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is building in Unity 2019.3+ > to Xcode 11.5+ and you get Mach-O-Link errors or _inflate errors or link failures this will fix it. However, remember to add libz.tbd to your UnityFramework Targets entry then go to BuildPhases > 'Link Binary with Libraries'. Then add the libz.tbd file at the top to add it to your UnityFramework Target. This fixed it for me.